# What is this type in webpack 5: "..."

Tags: typescript, webpack

Looking at the `types.d.ts` of **webpack**, I found `"..."` but I would like to know what it is.

For instance:

```
    rules?: (RuleSetRule | "...")[];
```

```
    minimizer?: (
        | ((this: Compiler, compiler: Compiler) => void)
        | WebpackPluginInstance
        | "..."
    )[];
```

See links:

- https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/main/types.d.ts#L6934
- https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/main/types.d.ts#L7725

Comment: It's a string literal type, it's the type of the value `"..."`. E.g. [here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#ruleparser) it says _'"..." refers to the defaults'_.